# How to use key word LIKE to search from LONG field in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to run a simple query in Oracle using key word `LIKE` to search in a `LONG` field. Here is the example:

```
SELECT SOMETHING
FROM MYTABLE
WHERE (LONGFIELD LIKE '%translate%' or LONGFIELD LIKE '%interpret%')
```

Below is the error:

```
inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got LONG
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: `LONG` has been deprecated for over 10 years now (Since 8i came out). Why are you still using it?

Comment: because i am still using Oracle 8i.

Comment: LONG has been deprecated with the release of 8i and the availability of the `CLOB` datatype. And you should **really** (I mean *really*) upgrade to a supported version.

Answer (score 0):

Per [this question (which admittedly is old, but I think still relevant)](http://dbaforums.org/oracle/index.php?showtopic=1164) you should be using the `CLOB` type. You cannot do what you want using a `LONG`